# pandas - integer type is required

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

my data type is float64, using below code to convert from object type.
input:

```
df.iloc[:,9:33]=df.iloc[:,9:33].apply(lambda x : x.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float))
```

when i tried to sum, i got the below error:

output:

```
TypeError: an integer is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5461a828af6e> in <module>()
----> 1 amount = df['Total'].sum()
   2 print(amount)
```

Comment: Why doesn't your question contain your data?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like bug for me, possible solution is not assign back but use [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
#sample data
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['aa45', 's789'], size=(5, 20)))
print(df)
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11  \
0  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  s789  aa45  s789  s789   
1  aa45  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789   
2  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  s789   
3  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789   
4  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  aa45  s789  s789   

     12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19  
0  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  aa45  
1  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  
2  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  
3  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  
4  s789  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45
```

Try your solution, but if assign back columns are converted to `object`s (`string`s):

```
df.iloc[:,9:13]=df.iloc[:,9:13].apply(lambda x : x.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float))
```

---

```
print (df)
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8   9    10   11   12  \
0  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  s789  45  789  789   45   
1  aa45  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  45   45  789  789   
2  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  45  789  789   45   
3  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  45   45  789  789   
4  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  45  789  789  789   

     13    14    15    16    17    18    19  
0  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  aa45  
1  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  
2  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  
3  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  
4  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45
```

```
print (df.dtypes)
0     object
1     object
2     object
3     object
4     object
5     object
6     object
7     object
8     object
9     object
10    object
11    object
12    object
13    object
14    object
15    object
16    object
17    object
18    object
19    object
dtype: object
```

Possible solution is filter first columns, columns for converting and last columns and join together by [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
a = df.iloc[:, :9]
#in real data change 13 to 33
b = df.iloc[:,9:13].apply(lambda x : x.str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(float))
#in real data change 13 to 33
c = df.iloc[:, 13:]

df = pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9      10     11  \
0  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  s789  45.0  789.0  789.0   
1  aa45  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  45.0   45.0  789.0   
2  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  45.0  789.0  789.0   
3  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  45.0   45.0  789.0   
4  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  45.0  789.0  789.0   

      12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19  
0   45.0  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  s789  aa45  
1  789.0  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  
2   45.0  aa45  s789  aa45  s789  aa45  aa45  s789  
3  789.0  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45  aa45  s789  
4  789.0  aa45  s789  s789  s789  aa45  aa45  aa45
```

```
print (df.dtypes)
0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7      object
8      object
9     float64
10    float64
11    float64
12    float64
13     object
14     object
15     object
16     object
17     object
18     object
19     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: hi same error , pls see my post again with actual data output

Comment: hi, think it is working now after few re-run of the code.

Comment: hmmm, no idea the same error again when i try to rerun the code again.

Comment: @okl - same problem with concat and `a,b,c` subDataFrames? Data are confidental?

Comment: but i want the header to be there as columns label

Comment: the error no more after i remove this code : df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.RangeIndex(len(df.columns)), df.columns])

Comment: @okl - Super, I think first you have 0,1,2 in first row of original csv, so bad comments (deleted)